# How to iterate Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl in React with Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage, es6-promise

I'm getting the list of all the file names in a directory and then I want to get the download urls and do a foreach loop to get them. My issue is the `tempUrls` is empty and I can't set the state of `urls`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import storage from "firebase/storage";
import  firebaseConfig from "../dropzone/config";

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    useRouteMatch,
    BrowserRouter,
    useParams
  } from "react-router-dom";


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

}else {
    firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}

  

const FolderPage = () => {

     // router is getting the current path name
    let {folder} = useParams();

    
    
    let fb_storage = firebase.storage();
    let storageRef = fb_storage.ref();  
    
    let rootRef = storageRef.child(folder);
    console.log(rootRef);

    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]); 
    const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);      


    const fileNames =  () =>{
       
        rootRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
            let temp = [];
            
            res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
                // console.log(folderRef.name)
               
                
                // All the prefixes under listRef.
                // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
            });
            
            res.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
                // All the items under listRef.
                temp.push(itemRef.name)
                console.log(itemRef.name);

               


            });
            setFiles(temp);

            
            
            }).catch(function(error) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            });
            
            let tempUrls = [];

            
            files.forEach(function(file){
                var fileRef =  storageRef.child( folder + '/' + file);

                // Get the download URL
                fileRef.getDownloadURL()
                    .then((url) => {
                    
                        tempUrls.push(url);
                        console.log(tempUrls)
                      
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        // A full list of error codes is available at
                        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
                        switch (error.code) {
                        case 'storage/object-not-found':
                            // File doesn't exist
                            break;
                        case 'storage/unauthorized':
                            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                            break;
                        case 'storage/canceled':
                            // User canceled the upload
                            break;
                    
                        // ...
                    
                        case 'storage/unknown':
                            // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
                            break;
                        }
                    });

            })
            

            
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fileNames();
    },[])

    
    


    return (
        <>
            <div>hello {folder}</div>
            {/* <div>hello {folders}</div> */}

            <ul>
                {files.map((file, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}> {file}</li>
                })}
            </ul>

            <div>
                {urls.map((url, index) => {
                   return <a key={index} href={url}> {url} </a>
                })}
                
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default FolderPage
```